# Download Audio Object through javascript

Tags: javascript, html, audio

How would you download an Audio object created dynamically?

```
var audioPlaying = new Audio();
audioPlaying.src = link;
audioPlaying.addEventListener("loadedmetadata", function(_event) {
    audioPlaying.play();
});
```

Comment: You can't download an object, but if you have an URL to a resource, like an audio file, you could download it. In the future, converting streams and buffers to downloadable data could probably be possible with the Web Audio API.

Comment: How would you download it if you had the URL, without using a link (an html <a> tag)

Comment: You would of course have to create an anchor with a download attribute, or use a serverside script with the right headers.

Comment: So the only way to do it would be something like '<a id="dl_Link" href="blah.com/blah.mp3" download="Blah Song"></a>'

Answer (score 1):

you could, if the audio source is shown somewhere on the website, enable the controls.
`audioPlaying.controls = true`
after which you can right-click the audio (now having the player visible on the page) and select "Save Audio As..."
(tested using firefox)